# How long can 'Window Station' name be on Windows?

Tags: windows, desktop

A windows session consists of all process and other system objects that represent a single user's logon session. Sessions contain Window Stations and Window Stations contain desktops.

What is the limit on length of 'Window Station' name?

I need to persist this information and need to define a fixed size that should be able to accommodate the longest' Window Station' name.

Comment: How long is a piece of string? You should enquire the required number of bytes needed to store the name in a preliminary call to `GetUserObjectInformationW`, before attempting to retrieve the actual name. Works the same way as many other WinAPI calls. BTW, what does this have to do with `win32gui`?

Comment: Hi @Adrian. I understand that. The ask here is how long can windows station name be? I need to persist this information and need to define a fixed size that should be able to accommodate the longest' Window Station' name.

Comment: Why do you think there's a limit since this is not documented? Not every string in computers/APIs have a maximum size defined (beyond integer sizes limits), fully variable-sized string is a very common pattern.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to persist an arbitrary length string?

Answer (score 0):

There is no obvious limit listed on MSDN so you have to assume there is no real limit other than a length <= UINT32.

If we look at the implementation details we can at least make some guesses. The documentation for `CreateWindowStation` says this about the name:

> Window station names are case-insensitive and cannot contain backslash characters (`\`).

This is a tiny hint and if we look at an old Sysinternals [blog post](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-blog-archive/pushing-the-limits-of-windows-user-and-gdi-objects-8211-part-1/ba-p/723881) we can confirm that they live in the [NT object manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_Manager_(Windows)). As most strings in the NT API, we are now looking at a `UNICODE_STRING` and our new limit is therefore 0x7fff WCHARs minus `strlen("WindowStations\\")`.